# What happens when a suicide operation transfer remaining funds to it’s own contract address?

Tags: selfdestruct

equivalent solidity code :

```
suicide(this);
```

Does the operation succeeds at not transferring the balances while still erasing the code ?
Or is contract’s code destroyed only after sending balances which means a recursion infinite loop can occur if the contract’s does no stop if called through this way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

My original answer was ***wrong***. Ether `selfdestruct`ed to a contract that's scheduled for deletion is actually completely destroyed.

Comment: Sending funds to a contract is calling it’s code so the still existing code of the contract being destroyed as nonce isn’t unset until the top end of the transaction, are you sure this works?

Comment: It's trivial to try, so I encourage you to do it. :-) But `selfdestruct` doesn't really "send funds to a contract". It _never_ invokes that contract's code.

Comment: Perhaps there's some strange happening with CREATE2 but in this article's notes (near the end) 
https://blog.ricmoo.com/wisps-the-magical-world-of-create2-5c2177027604, they mention that if you send ether to a contract scheduled for deletion it will _simply vanish._

Comment: Interesting! I stand corrected. Editing my answer.